# magento 2 add product combine sku, name into url_key

Tags: magento2

Could I find the way to save ***url key*** by combine the ***sku*** attribute and ***name*** attribute on the time of add product. i don't want to write module or extension just need a clue how its happen on vendor/magento through code sample.

Comment: means you want to store sku + name  as url key of respective product ??

Comment: is this difficult?

Answer (score 2):

The product URL key is set in `\Magento\CatalogUrlRewrite\Observer\ProductUrlKeyAutogeneratorObserver` listening the `catalog_product_save_before` event.

The `\Magento\CatalogUrlRewrite\Model\ProductUrlPathGenerator::getUrlKey` method is used to generate the key.